# Is it possible to chain multiple ex commands together with a single range?

Tags: ex-mode, range, rearrangement

I often want to move and indent code at the same time. Is it possible to do the following.

Original text:

```
1: var x = foo();
2: bar(x);
```

Desired text:

```
1: setTimeout(function(){
2:     var x = foo();
3:     bar(x);
4: });
```

Working keystrokes:

1. Place the cursor on line 1.
2. Type `O` (insert text on the line above) and type the two lines `setTimeout(function(){` and `});`. Press escape to exit insert mode.
3. Type `3,4> | 3,4m1`.

Is it possible to condense step 3 into something like the following:

`3,4>m1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: no.

You can use the `:global` command to pick some lines to operate
on, and then give a sequence of commands to operate on those
selected lines:

```
:3,4 g/^/ > | m1
```

We're only interested in the range, but `:g` also wants a pattern.
So in this case we'll just use `/^/` which will always match in a
line.

This however moves each line in sequence which reverses the order
of the moved lines. A simple way to rectify this is to mark the
last inserted line (line 2 at this point) before you start the
`:global` and move the indented lines *before* it:

```
:k x | 3,4 g/^/ > | m 'x-
```

Or you could shift each line up by 2, provided you know you've
inserted exactly 2 new lines:

```
:3,4 g/^/ > | m-2
```

That's hardly a condensing of the original command but shows the
general principle.

Another option is to indent your lines, and then use the `'[` and `']`
marks, which delimit previously changed text:

```
:3,4> | '[,']m1
```

This still isn't a condensing, but for more complicated ranges it may be worth
the effort, and might be your best bet. But maybe for simple edits do the simple thing.

Finally: I guess we're talking about general principles here. But in this
particular case, after your step #2, the Normal mode commands `dd>jjp` would
also achieve the same result.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but unfortunately, this reverses the lines, presumably because it executes "indent then move to line 1" for every line, rather than once for the entire range.

Comment: Of course it does. See edit.